# How to convert a LEAD to Person-Account directly (without any API or code)?

Tags: leads, lead-conversion, person-accounts, b2c, b2b

Is it possible to convert a Lead to Person-Account directly similar to normal B2B accounts. I read it somewhere as, we need to keep the Company field in Lead as blanks to convert the Lead Contact directly to a Person-Account.

But I can see the `Company field as a mandatory one in Lead`. In normal B2B while converting the Lead the `Company is mapped to Account` as a Business Account and `lead Contact as normal contact` and Company name as Opportunity name (Optional) and a Task.

Or this can only be done via API or Apex only? Can someone please help em on this? Thanks in Advance

Comment: It would help if you had a link to the reference that you mention in the first paragraph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this answer at [Salesforce Developer Forums](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000MNFHIA4), it appears that when Person Accounts are enabled in your Org you can make the Company on Lead optional and remove it from the page layout.

> Do you have Person accounts enabled in your Salesforce org?  You can only do this through Support, and the change is irreversible once enabled.  I am currently testing this out for a perpective client in a developer org.
>
> If you do not have Person accounts enabled, you will not be able to change the Company field on the lead layout to no longer be required.  Once Person accounts are enabled, this requirement is relaxed and you can remove the "Required" flag on the necessary page layouts (or remove the field altogether if you really don't need it).  With that no longer required, Leads without Company information will convert to Person accounts.

I remember being able to do this with an org where we had Person Accounts enabled for leads, but you need a different record type and page layout for the Person Accounts where the Company could be made optional. Which is recommended in the [Salesforce Help](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=leads_notes.htm&language=en_US) for this.

Comment: This is also backed up by the [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=leads_notes.htm)

Comment: @FernandoGavinho - thanks - added that link and remembering my experience with this.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me, record types active for profiles: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385750&type=1